# ScrollView does not show in relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

This is what I am trying to implement:

[image]

The visibility of the adview can be toggled to either visible or gone. This is a layout which I used and is working without the two buttons.

This is the xml for with the scrollview and the adview, without the buttons. (scrollview works)

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"

    android:visibility="visible" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"

    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

        android:stretchColumns="0">

        <TableRow>
            //scrollable content here
        </TableRow

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I try to implement scenario A by encapsulating the adView element inside a TableLayout, so I can attempt to use TableRows to implement the buttons.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"

        android:visibility="visible" />

    </TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tableLayout"
    .....
```

When I use this approach, my scrollview disappears. Where am I going wrong and how can I resolve this and get to scenario A?

Comment: Have you tried to set height for `TableLayout` to `match_parent`? Is your tablelayout parent layout for your second scenario?

Comment: I just tried to set to match_parent but to no avail. the second scenario I still maintain the outer container of RelativeLayout.

Comment: `android:layout_above="@id/adView"`  add like this `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` ur missing + here

Comment: Show your whole xml for scenario A

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the attribute 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"' from TableLayout that you had in AdView. This aligns the table in top of the parent relative layout although your intention was to put it in the bottom.